# Unable to upload file to OneDrive via Teams bot due to "scp or roles claim" error message

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am currently working on a Microsoft Teams bot that aims to upload files to OneDrive in order to share the URL with a user based on a chat request. However, I'm facing a recurring issue with the error message "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token."

Here's a breakdown of what I'm doing and the steps I've taken:

***Step 1: Initial Authentication Request***

I initiate the authentication process with the following POST request:

```
POST /<MY TENANT ID>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Authorization: Bearer <MY ACCESS TOKEN>

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<MY APP ID>&client_secret=<MY APP PASSWORD>&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com
```

This successfully returns a bearer access token that I use for further interactions.

***Step 2: File Upload Request***

With the access token in hand, I proceed to upload a plaintext file containing just the content "Hello world". Here's the POST request I'm using:

```
POST /v1.0/drive/root:/filename.txt:/content HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer <MY ACCESS TOKEN>
Content-Type: text/plain

hello_world
```

However, the response that I'm getting is:

```
{"error": {"code": "AccessDenied", "message": "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.", "innerError": {"date": "2023-08-11T20:51:52", "request-id": "e7bb0afc-d6ce-348e-b6cf-7cba046e70b4", "client-request-id": "e7bb0afc-d6ce-4f07-b6cf-7cba046e7222"}}}
```

My questions are:

1. Are the missing permissions in my initial authentication request or within the bot's configuration in Azure?
2. If the permissions need to be set in the bot's Azure configuration, what specific permissions are missing? The error message mentions "scp or roles claim," and I'm unsure what this actually means. Does this mean "scp" and/or "roles" need to be in my initial authentication request, or am I misinterpreting that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if you miss adding required **API permission** in the app registration or missed granting **admin consent** to it.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **`Files.ReadWrite.All`** permission of **Application** type by adding consent:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appID
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

To check whether the token has **permission** or not, you can decode it by pasting the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and find **`roles`** claim in it:

[image]

Now, use below **PUT** request to upload a plaintext file containing just the content "Hello world" by including `userID` in it:

```http
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/drive/root:/srifile.txt:/content
Authorization: Bearer <MY ACCESS TOKEN>
Content-Type: text/plain

hello_world
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in user's OneDrive where file created successfully like below:

[image]

When I opened above text file, it has **`hello_world`** in it:

[image: u]

Comment: This is extremely helpful - thank you! Do you know if providing permission of Files.ReadWrite.All will provide access to read/write of everyone's sharepoint sites or is this specific to the application? I don't have access to our Azure portal but I've been given the green light to go and just let IT know so they can approve it, but wanted to make sure this wasn't going to create security risks by allowing access to other sites.

Comment: Note that, providing `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission of **Application** type allows the app to read, create, update, and delete all files in **all site collections** without a signed in user. To confirm that, you can check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-37).

Comment: If you prefer least privileges, then you have to change to **Delegated** flows like authorization code flow, username password etc... for generating token and by granting permissions of `Delegated` type that gives access to only signed-in user's files by referring this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-37) based on your requirement.

Comment: Ahh ok gotcha. Since this is a large organization, I assume they wouldn't give that permission since it'd expose a significant amount of more access than necessary. It's a shame that there isn't a specific permission for just the application to share files back and forth without exposing excessive access or requiring user authentication interaction. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Just learned that you can give an application permission to specifically to write to one SharePoint site. Apparently you need another application that has full control to grant only "write" permissions to the other application specifically to that site: https://dev.to/svarukala/use-microsoft-graph-to-set-granular-permissions-to-sharepoint-online-sites-for-azure-ad-application-4l12